# Как на canvas-е нарисовать сетку?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

Как на canvas-е нарисовать обычную сетку?
Вообщем суть в том, что шарик должен отрисовываться на сетке. Но каждый раз перерисовывать сетку затратно.
Можно ли один раз нарисовать фон в виде сетки и наложить на него канвас,где будет шарик и перерисовывать его?
Или что-то подобное...
Спасибо

---

```
<body width="100%" height="100%">
<img id="cimg" />
<div id="cdiv" style="width:100%;height:100%"/>


<script  >
var scale = window.devicePixelRatio;
var width = window.innerWidth/scale;
var height = window.innerHeight/scale;

        var cnv = document.createElement("canvas");
        cnv.width = width;
        cnv.height = height;
        var ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");
        ctx.strokeStyle = "grey";
        var w = cnv.width - 1;
        var h = cnv.height - 1;
        var span = 45;
        for (var x = -0.5; x < w; x += span) ctx.strokeRect(x, 0, 0.1, h);
        for (var y = -0.5; y < h; y += span) ctx.strokeRect(0, y, w, 0.1);
        // сохрнить в рисунок
        document.images["cimg"].src = cnv.toDataURL();

        //$("#cimg").attr("src", cnv.toDataURL());
        // добавить как фон для div
        document.getElementById("cdiv").style="background-image: url('" + cnv.toDataURL() + "')";





document.onmousemove = function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  cnv.width = cnv.width;

  x = e.clientX;
  y = e.clientY;
  ctx.arc(x,y,10,0,Math.PI*2,true); 
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#111";
  ctx.stroke();
};
```

Comment: а нельзя иметь прозрачный канвас а под ним фоновая картинка с сеткой?

Comment: я подумал так....а если разрешение нужно сделать, как,скажем по размеру 5 стандартных мониторов? Хотя идея- repeat написать в фоне ....

Comment: ну конечно repeat. даже картинку сделать можно просто из одной клетки :):):):)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функции для создания изображений сетки и шарика

```
<script>
    function grid(width, height, span) {
        var cnv = document.createElement("canvas");
        cnv.width = width;
        cnv.height = height;
        var ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");
        ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
        var w = cnv.width - 1;
        var h = cnv.height - 1;
        for (var x = -0.5; x < w; x += span) ctx.strokeRect(x, 0, 0.1, h);
        for (var y = -0.5; y < h; y += span) ctx.strokeRect(0, y, w, 0.1);
        return cnv.toDataURL();
    }
    function ball(color, size) {
        var cnv = document.createElement("canvas");
        cnv.width = size;
        cnv.height = size;
        var ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");
        ctx.arc(size / 2, size / 2, size / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.stroke();
        return cnv.toDataURL();
    }
    function bounds(selector) {
        var t = $(selector);
        var o = t.offset()
        return { width: t.width(), height: t.height(), left: o.left, top: o.top };
    }
</script>
```

---

Контейнер для шарика

```
<style>
    #cdiv {  
      margin-left: 100px; 
      width: 220px; 
      height: 120px; 
      position: relative; 
      border: 1px solid gray; 
    }
</style>

<div id="cdiv"><img id="cball" /></div>
```

---

Вывод изображений сетки и шарика, а также обработка событий мыши для движения шарика

```
<script>
$(function () {
  $('#cball').attr("src", ball("navy", 30));
  $('#cdiv').css("background-image", "url('" + grid(220, 120, 5) + "')");
  $("#cdiv").on('mousemove', function (e) {
     var b = bounds('#cball');
     var d = bounds('#cdiv');
     var p = { x: e.pageX - d.left - b.width / 2, y: e.pageY - d.top - b.height / 2 };
     if (p.x > 0 && p.x < d.width - b.width && p.y > 0 && p.y < d.height - b.height) {
        $('#cball').css({ 'left': p.x, 'top': p.y, 'position': 'absolute' });
     }
  });
});
</script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```
<img id="cimg" />
<div id="cdiv" style="width:220px;height:120px;"/>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var cnv = document.createElement("canvas");
        cnv.width = 220;
        cnv.height = 120;
        var ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");
        ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
        var w = cnv.width - 1;
        var h = cnv.height - 1;
        var span = 5;
        for (var x = -0.5; x < w; x += span) ctx.strokeRect(x, 0, 0.1, h);
        for (var y = -0.5; y < h; y += span) ctx.strokeRect(0, y, w, 0.1);
        // сохрнить в рисунок
        $("#cimg").attr("src", cnv.toDataURL());
        // добавить как фон для div
        $('#cdiv').css("background-image", "url('" + cnv.toDataURL() + "')");
    });
</script>
```

Пример созданной сетки, которая выводит в img и в div

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я перерисовываю его. А как оставить сетку?

Comment: document.onmousemove = function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  canvas.width = canvas.width;
  x = e.clientX;
  y = e.clientY;
  ctx.arc(x,y,10,0,Math.PI*2,true); 
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#111";
  ctx.stroke();
};

Comment: @RakzinRoman _"А как оставить сетку?"_ -- в примере сетка сохраняется в img. т.е. она остается. и перерисовывать не надо.

Comment: у меня срабатывает событие onmousemove - в нём я перерисовываю координаты шарика. Что б очистить предыдущее его местоположение я очищаю канвас...соответственно и сетка стирается. Просто как удалить шарик, не трогая сетку? вот это интересно. В крайнем случае- можно код перерисовки сетки кинуть туда, но, может-можно как-то оптимизировать? Хотя и на этом- спасибо большое.

Comment: а....понял....я не весь Ваш код взял и у меня не то получилось. Ок

Comment: @RakzinRoman _"как удалить шарик, не трогая сетку?"_ -- сетку надо сделать как background-image для div -- добавил в ответ. а шарик внутри div можно двигать и удалить. фон останется.

Comment: @RakzinRoman _"я не весь Ваш код взял и у меня не то получилось."_ -- а с добавлением в background-image получилось?

Comment: Да. Спасибо )))

Comment: у меня что-то получилось, что шарика теперь не видно...(( я код изменил в вопросе. Получается картинка стала на первый план...

Comment: @RakzinRoman  _"шарика теперь не видно"_ -- т.е. надо под мышью выводить шарик фиксированного размера? и чтобы шарик выводился над сеткой?

Comment: Да. А вообще потом- нужно сделать, как в игре agar.io ,но сейчас хотя б так разобраться

Comment: @RakzinRoman шарик надо нарисовать также как и сетку. один раз. сохранить в img. и при движении мыши двигать этот img.

Comment: я понял Вас. А если такая ситуация- будут 2 шарика и они рядом- не получится там на самом деле 2 квадрата-т.к. фотка квадратная...или норм будет.?(ну всмысле фон transparent или там начнутся проблемы?)

Comment: @RakzinRoman _"не получится там на самом деле 2 квадрата"_ -- нет, т.к. gif с прозрачным фоном

Comment: @RakzinRoman _"не получится там на самом деле 2 квадрата-т.к. фотка квадратная...или норм будет.?"_ -- фон шарика не выводится. добавил еще один ответ.