# Просчёт скорости шарика, в зависимости от удалённости от него

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

Есть шарик в центре- я мышку отвожу на определённое расстояние от него и если это расстояние большое- он двигается быстрее на координатной сетке. Если курсор на шарике- он стоит. Пример есть в игре http://agar.io/ .
Как этот просчёт реализовать?
Спасибо

Comment: в игре двигается сетка с разной скоростью, которая зависит от расстояния между шариком и мышью.

Comment: @Stack на самом деле в игре двигаются шарики, в том числе и шарики игрока, и даже в случае если игрок состоит из единственного шарика - этот шарик все равно двигается - в пространстве игрового поля. А то что на экране этот шарик обычно в центре так это все благодаря камере, которая всегда смотрит в центр масс шариков игрока.

Answer (score 1):

Будем считать, что координаты центра окружности и курсора вам известы. Тогда
Уравнение окружности с центром в точке (x0, y0) и радиусом R выглядит так

```
(x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 = R^2
```

Для точки с координатами (x1, y1), лежащей внутри окружности, должно выполняться условие

```
(x1 - x0)^2 + (y1 - y0)^2 <= R^2
```

Для нахождения же расстояния между двумя точками с заданными координатами используйте формулу

```
sqrt((x1 - x0)^2 + (y1 - y0)^2)
```

[Расстояние между точками](http://mathematics.ru/courses/stereometry/content/chapter9/section/paragraph4/theory.html#.Vqz8Rajp2WM)

[Уравнение окружности](http://mathematics.ru/courses/planimetry/content/chapter10/section/paragraph3/theory.html#.Vqz8Xajp2WM)

Также обратите внимание на руководство по `canvas` [вот здесь](http://htmlhook.ru/rukovodstvo-po-html5-canvas.html). Там, среди прочего, есть и примеры работы с мышью. Например, фрагмент кода для отслеживания координат мыши

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
var x = e.pageX = this.offsetLeft;
var y = e.pageY = this.offsetTop;
var div = document.getElementById("coords");
div.innerHTML = "x: " + x + " y: " + y;
};
```

Comment: код для рисования на canvas и движение уже есть. [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/487667/196972)